# Visual Studio\blend artboard render differently from device

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend, windows-phone, winrt-xaml

We have a strange problem with pixel perfect markups. Vs or Blend artboard render pages not similary as device (biggest problem with textblocks). I think picture is better description.

[image]

and code for full information

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Image
        Source="Untitled.png"/>
    <TextBlock
        Margin="12 7"
        FontSize="34"
        Text="Segoe UI Super TEST" />
</Grid>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any chance that image you're plopping in there has the same words on it causing that ghost text?

Answer (score 0):

Folks, thanks for spended time. Problem wasn't with ghost text, that caused by simple background image. The main issue was that text is lower in device, than in artboard.

Fortunately, we found solution. Somehow I lost Segoe WP on my machine, I don't know why it was not reinstall with sdk. So default FontFamily  mapping to PhontFamilyNormal which was mapping to unexisting font. And this cause broke rendering.